# How can I load a 2D array of integers from a JSON file?

Tags: java, processing

I have a JSON file that, among other things, contains various 2D arrays. [Here](https://pastebin.com/KcFmScXT) is a link to a copy of the file. I want to load things such as "floor" into an int[][] array. I can't seem to find any way to do that. I might also be storing the array incorrectly, I'm not sure. I create the JSON file with a python script.

When I use processing's "loadJSONObject" function and access "floor", it says that it is a "processing.data.JSONArray" but I can't index it like a normal array. If I try to, it gives the error "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object"

If I try to index it with ".getIntArray" like in [this](https://processing.org/reference/JSONArray_getIntArray_.html) example, it gives the error "The function getIntArray() does not exist."

Here is some code, since I can't link pastebin without it:

```
JSONObject currentLevel;
currentLevel = loadJSONObject("assets/levels/test_level.json");
println(currentLevel.get("floor").getIntArray());
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Since it's a 2-dimensional array of integers, it's an array **of arrays** of integers. Right? So. Look again at the [main documentation page, one level up from the example](https://processing.org/reference/JSONArray.html). Do you see anything relevant to access an array from the array-of-arrays? Anyway, please read [ask] and try to ask a *specific* question, [rather than](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) "any help is appreciated".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I did look at that page, and I did not see anything of use. Perhaps I missed something. I can't tell if you are being helpful or just condescending. Also, is my title not a specific question? "Any help is appreciated" is not the question I asked. I asked _specifically_, "How can I load a 2D array of integers from a JSON file?"

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation, one level up](https://processing.org/reference/JSONArray.html):

> `getJSONArray()`: Retrieves the `JSONArray` with the associated index value

After we get the `floor` data (e.g. `floor = currentlevel.getJSONArray("floor")`), it is itself an array *of arrays* of integers. Processing represents this with its `JSONArray` type, which apparently does not support indexing. We also cannot convert it to a plain array of integers, because it *doesn't represent one* - in the same way that we cannot treat an `int[][]` as if it were an `int[]` in Java.

Instead: use `getJSONArray` on `floor` to get the individual arrays of integers; and *those* can then be converted using `getIntArray`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do it like this: using **getJSONArray()**

```
JSONObject currentLevel;
currentLevel = loadJSONObject("assets/levels/test_level.json");

JSONArray array = currentLevel.getJSONArray("floor");

print(array)
```

Ref:

[JSONArray_getJSONArray](https://processing.org/reference/JSONArray_getJSONArray_.html)

Comment: Right idea, but wrong implementation. OP is already able to get the `floor` data. The problem is accessing "rows" of that data, which represents a 2-dimensional array.